# strange issue where button visibility remains default value

Tags: c#

I have a very large ASP.NET application in C#.

The issue is simple yet difficult/strange. No matter where in the code I try to change the visibility of the button, it retains its default value whether I set that to true or false.

I am not sure what could be causing this so I thought I might take a shot at asking for opinions here.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code and markup here..

Comment: May be you are using UpdatePanels or You are setting that button's visibility on every postback to its default value, You should trace each & every line from page_load.

Comment: i cant really post the code or else I would..It is a very large program and the button is used is various places so I am looking for more of a generic approach on deubgging this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Visible` property inherits it's state from parent controls.

For example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Visible="false" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="click me" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The `Button` will never be visible, as long as the container control `Panel1` is invisible.

Implementation of `Control.Visible`:

```
public virtual bool Visible
{
    get
    {
        return !this.flags[16] 
        && (this._parent == null || this.DesignMode || this._parent.Visible);
    }
    set
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So when `parent != null && !visible`, the child control is invisible.

Comment: the button is visible if I change its default value to true. the container it is in is always visible.

Comment: Why don't you include these informations in your question? You should also show some code, for example a reduced version of your aspx.

Comment: I have solved the problem...it was very strange...when I ran my program again all of a sudden, the button follows proper code behaviour :S Visual studio bug? EDIT: Actually I give up, sometimes when I run the code without change the buttons follow proper behaviour and other times they dont...this is all with the same code running but recompiling >_>. @Tim Schmelter I think this is some IDE bug

Comment: This has probably become non programming related question...When I rerun the code at one time or another it will follow the actual code behaviour :S.

Comment: @Nadal: Never heard of such a bug, but you might want post it on MS Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: I asked a coworker and he said that during one of his college courses of programming his professor told him an old VS bug is that VS will run strangely at random if you dont rebuild it after every code change. This happens at random so if your code isn't behaving properly then rebuild it. For me however, the situation is worse as the code runs differently after each compilation..

Comment: This wasnt the case with my problem but I learned something new so I guess it will add to the SO question bank in an effective manner